# Does a method return an object require return null statement after try/catch block?

Tags: java

I ran into following code snippets. One method requires return statement but the other doesn't. I believe Case 2) requires "return null" statement but a compiler complains. I am not sure why.

Case 1) If I remove "return null" statement, a compiler complains that it needs it.

```
 private Foo createFoo(Bar bar, Baz baz) throws SomeException {
    try {
        if (...) {
            // perform computation to return foo object
            ......
            return foo;
        } 
        else if (...) {
            // perform computation to return foo object
            ......
            return foo;
        }
    } catch(SomeException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        throw se;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Case 2) If I add "return null" statement then a compiler complains that unreachable code.

```
private Foo createFoo2(Bar bar, Baz baz) throws SomeException {
    try {
        // perform computation to return foo object
        ......
        return foo;
    } catch (SomeException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        throw se;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if neither your first or second condition is matched? i.e. neither `if (...)` nor `else if (...)`? You need to return something for that case.

Comment: What @AndyTurner said. The first case, you could exit the try statement. second one a return is inevitable in the try, thus statements after the catch are unreachable

Comment: yes, that I understand and makes sense it requires return null statement.

Comment: Well... if you understand that, it's unclear what you're asking. No, you don't require a `return` after the try/catch, provided all code paths inside the try/catch terminate the method's execution (i.e. either return or throw on all code paths). That provision isn't met in the first case (so a return is required after), but it is in the second (so no return is required after).

Comment: To put it simply, if the compiler says 'missing return statement', you need it, but if it says 'unreachable code', you should remove it.

Comment: Thank you Andy Turner and Tyler for your reply. I think I understand now for the case 2). There is no condition to match and return is inevitable either null or real foo.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, it's possible for program flow to reach the final `}` of the method.  In particular, this will happen if neither `if` statement evaluates to `true`.  So you need to tell the program what to return in that case.

In your second example, it's NOT possible for program flow to reach the final `}` of the method.  So it doesn't make any sense for you to tell the program what to return in that case; and the compiler is protecting you from writing something that doesn't make sense, by flagging it as an error.